# How to create a complete group tab to admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, database-connection

I want to add a group tab in

> system > configuration > general > general.

This tab will contain a text area where the user will be able to modify the text.

This text area will be connected with the database. When the user modifies the text then it will also be modified in database.

How can I do that?
I have already created a new group tab but how I can connect it with my model ??

cf this to understand: https://prnt.sc/oqfgou

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

try following way..

In file

> app/code/local/Namesapce/Modulename/etc/system.xml

```
<general>            
       <groups>
            <test translate="label">
                    <label>Test Options</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <custom_text_box>
                            <label>Textbox Label</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </custom_text_box>                       
                    </fields>
                </test>
        </groups>
   </general>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i already did that, now i need to be able to connect my tab to my model

Comment: @TheoCerutti you want to this filed value get in your module model

Comment: i want to display my database field in this textarea and be able to modify it

Comment: @TheoCerutti this is not possible here always system config value store in `core_config_data` table

Comment: ok ok so i can't do it because i'm in the general tab, so if i want to create a new tab and put my group in it how can i do?